# How to tell if two numbers are really different or they are actually the same due to floating point error

Tags: matlab

For example,

`0.168033639538270`
and 
 `0.168033639538270`

are two `double` type numbers that are from two different calculations (some further calculations from the eigenvalues of a matrix).

But they are treated as different by MATLAB (by `unique` or `==`). How do I know if MATLAB treats them as different due to floating point error `eps = 2.220446049250313e-16`, or if they are actually different (the digits behind the first 15 digits are not the same, but MATLAB just will not display them). Sometimes MATLAB treats two number with the same display value as the same, but sometimes different, so I want to know if they are really different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print a formatted version of the number at required precision using `sprintf`, and then compare the two strings using `strcmp`.

Comment: Thanks. can i print beyond the double-type `1e-15` bound?

Comment: Yes you can; you can print up to arbitrary precision; whether that represents actual precision or not, however, is debatable. Try `sprintf('%.100f', pi)` to see what I mean.